# UIView (placed inside scrollview) is not showing its subviews when it's height constant was changed programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I've made the following arrangement in my xib file.

```
--> UIScrollView (top-0, leading-0, trailing-0, bottom-0) to SafeView
-----> Container_UIView (top-0, leading-0, trailing-0, bottom-0, equal height - priority 250, equal width) to UIScrollview
---------> First_UIView (top-0, leading-0, trailing-0, height - 250) to Container_UIView and (vertical spacing- 0 ) to Second_UIView
---------> Second_UIView (leading-0, trailing-0, bottom - 0) to Container_UIView and (vertical spacing- 0 ) to First_UIView
------------> UIlabel (top-0, leading-0, trailing-0) to Second_UIView  and (vertical spacing - 0) to Button
------------> Button ( leading-0, trailing-0, bottom - 0, height - 50) to Second_UIView and (vertical spacing - 0) to UIlabel
```

I made `UIlabel` with dynamic height. I changed the `Second_View` height programmatically. The height was changed but the subviews were not shown only clear color background was visible as in the figure below. In figure, left side is of debug view and the right side is from simulator. Debug view is showing there are subviews but the simulator is not showing those subviews. I've highlighted the subviews with the red mark in the figure. In figure image is the background, the label is inside Second_View and the container_uiview is clear color. In viewcontroller I changed the height using the following code:

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *view in self.Second_View.subviews)
    if (!view.hidden)
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);

self.Second_ViewHeight.constant = contentRect.size.height;
```

Is there a way so that subviews will be visible after changing its height constant programmatically.

[image]

Comment: Which is the first_uiview and which is the second_uiview in the picture ? point them out clearly. Where the multiline text(label/textview) and image are coming from ? and what is the point of `contentRect.size.height=contentRect.size.height` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use UITableView instead of ScrollView. Because this kind of UI is easy to handle with tableView.

Answer (score 0):

after adjusting UILabel size, i.e. its height, try calling method layoutIfNeeded() or layoutSubviews()